# CXF IllegalAnnotationException related to no-arg StackTraceElement constructor

Tags: java, cxf

I have a web service built using Apache CXF 2.1.3. One of the web params is a java.lang.Throwable. When I call JaxWsServerFactoryBean.setServiceBean, I get an IllegalAnnotationException as java.lang.StackTraceElement doesn't have a no-arg constructor.

The JIRA bug report [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-1592?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) claims to have fixed the problem, but I am still getting the exception. Any ideas?

I am using java 1.6.0_11.

Comment: I think you should take this up with the CXF developers.  If you say the bug is not fixed, report it to them

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating to CXF 2.1.5?

Comment: CXF 2.1.5 and 2.2.1 give the same problem. java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.

Comment: Dan, since when can you pass a throwable in an SEI at all?

Comment: Good point.  Throwable isn't mappable into a JAXB type and thus isn't usable as a parameter or return value.